# @Bean inside class with @Configuration and without it

Tags: java, spring

There is a `@Bean` annotation in Spring 3.0. It allows to define a Spring bean directly in a Java code. While browsing Spring reference I found two different ways of using this annotation - inside class annotated with `@Configuration` and inside class which doesn't have this annotation.

[This section](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-factorybeans-annotations) contains following piece of code:

```
@Component
public class FactoryMethodComponent {

   @Bean @Qualifier("public")
   public TestBean publicInstance() {
      return new TestBean("publicInstance");
   }

   // omitted irrelevant method
}
```

[And here](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-java-basic-concepts) we could see a very similar piece of code, but now `@Configuration` is in the place:

```
@Configuration
public class AppConfig {
   @Bean
   public MyService myService() {
      return new MyServiceImpl();
   }
}
```

Former section of reference contains following explaination:

*The @Bean methods in a Spring component are processed differently than their counterparts inside a Spring @Configuration class. The difference is that @Component classes are not enhanced with CGLIB to intercept the invocation of methods and fields. CGLIB proxying is the means by which invoking methods or fields within @Configuration classes @Bean methods create bean metadata references to collaborating objects. Methods are not invoked with normal Java semantics. In contrast, calling a method or field within a @Component classes @Bean method has standard Java semantics.*

But CGLIB is a kind of internal stuff which application developer shouldn't be aware of (in a ideal world, of course). As I understand in both cases Spring invokes method annotated with `@Bean` to create Spring bean, in both cases these instances are injected to collaborators.

So my question is **what is the difference for me as an application developer between this two cases**?

Comment: You can't really ignore the CGLIB stuff. By doing so, you can get weird side-effects that don't make apparent sense.

Comment: @skaffman that's why I added "in ideal world". But I think that whole idea of Spring is to hide as many internal as possible, particularly proxifying mechanism, from application developer.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The difference is that with `@Configuration` you can call one `@Bean` method from another and get a fully initialized instance, as follows:

```
public class Foo {
    @Value("Hello, world!")
    public String value;
}

@Configuration
public class Config {
    @Bean
    public Foo createFoo() {
        Foo foo = new Foo();
        System.out.println(foo.value); // Prints null - foo not initialized yet
        return foo;
    }

    @Bean
    public Bar createBar() {
        Foo foo = createFoo();
        System.out.println(foo.value); // Prints Hello, world! - foo have been initialized by the interceptor
        return new Bar(foo);
    }
}
```

Comment: more importantly you can find the reference documentation for this behavior in the last paragraph of [section 3.10.4](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/reference/beans.html#beans-factorybeans-annotations) of the same version of documentation referenced in the question.

Answer (score 7):

**@Bean [instance method] inside @Component** - One method with @Bean instance call other method @Bean instance , then it    would be simple java semantics call i.e. Object won't returned by Spring container , It would be normal return from java instance factory method,because Component class don't extends CGLIB.

**@Bean  [instance method] inside @Configuration** - In this case , spring container would be returning reference to exisiting object. It won't be normal java sematic call.

**@Bean on static method inside Configuration & Component Class** - In this case , @Bean method would never be intercepted by the container neither in Configuration class nor in Component Sterotype class.

Comment: Component classes do extend CGLIB otherwise they could not use AOP.