# Getting Spring beans by method invocation vs new operator

Tags: java, spring

I am confused about this little topic. Somewhere I read that if a class is annotated with `@Component`, it is spring managed bean and whenever it is required, spring will provide it. I am confusing it with scope of a bean. Let me explain:

Let's say a class

```
@Component
public class Example{ }
```

If I instantiate this class in other class using `new Example()`, would container always provide me the same Example object all the time? Or would it return me new object every time?

Here comes the confusing part:

If in the same class I have two beans like this:

```
@Component
public class Example {
    @Bean DataSource sqlDataSource() {
         // some logic
    }
    @Bean @Scope("prototype") SomeObject getSomeObject() {
         return new SomeObject(sqlDataSource()); //**
    }

}
```

What will happen in this case? sqlDataSource() method invocation would return the same object again and again every time SomeObject bean is requested, or new instance of DataSource will be returned every time SomeObject is requested?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Bean is a method-level annotation that indicates Spring to create a bean when that method is invoked. It means to have the same functionality thatn  tag in XML config.

This annotation must be used inside of a @Configuration annotated class, otherwise if you invoke the method from another method it will be a normal java new operation, not spring's. See this post --> [@Bean inside class with @Configuration and witout it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3330618/bean-inside-class-with-configuration-and-witout-it)

Bearing this in mind new SomeObject(sqlDataSource()); would be equal to new SomeObject(new SqlDataSource());

if you annotate Example with @Configuration what will happen is that you'll get always a new SomeObject instance with the same sqlDataSource object, this means that Spring will take care of creating ONLY ONE sqlDataSource because it is singleton.

Answer (score 1):

```
@Bean DataSource sqlDataSource() {
     // some logic
}
```

This defines a singleton instance of DataSource. So everytime you request an instance of SomeObject a new SomeObject will be created (while it is defined in the prototype scope) but all of them will share the same DataSource object (since it's a singleton bean).