# Are Spring @component classes really not CGLIB extended?

Tags: spring, lookup, spring-bean

So im studying for the spring core certification and i came to the issue of the @lookup method injection which makes a component class cglib proxied, yet when we get to "lite" beans, meaning @Bean on non @configuration classes i keep reading that @component classes  don't extend CGLIB so that's why everytime we call the lite bean method a new instance will be created.
I am missing something here?

Comment: Does this answer your question ? https://stackoverflow.com/a/51620973/4214241

Comment: So even though you can actually get CGLIB proxies of @component classes, the Bean methods wont be, is that it?

Comment: '@Configuration' proxies the method call annotated with '@Bean' . For this reason , the same instance is returned on multiple calls to the method., 'lite-mode' does not and a new instance of the bean will be returned on each call to the method.

Comment: I understand but its false saying that the reason is because
@Component classes are not CGLIB proxied.

Comment: Could you please share the source ?

Comment: https://www.logicbig.com/tutorials/spring-framework/spring-core/bean-definition-in-components.html
Where it says: @Component classes are not CGLIB proxied.

Also here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/34810476/382115

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206159/discussion-between-r-g-and-maxrunner).